# Is there a way to Edit the TextColor of the text inside Toasts in Windows8

Tags: xaml, windows-8

Is there a way to Edit the TextColor of the text inside Toasts in Windows8 ?

Created like this.

```
var toastXml = new XmlDocument();
var title = toastXml.CreateElement("toast");
var visual = toastXml.CreateElement("visual");
visual.SetAttribute("version", "1");
visual.SetAttribute("lang", "en-US");
var binding = toastXml.CreateElement("binding");
binding.SetAttribute("template", "ToastImageAndText02");
image.SetAttribute("src", ActualPathToSet);

//Here the Text is assigned
var heading = toastXml.CreateElement("text");
heading.SetAttribute("id", "1");
heading.InnerText = R.GetResourceString("Hello World");

title.AppendChild(visual);
visual.AppendChild(binding);
binding.AppendChild(image);
binding.AppendChild(heading);
var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
```

I have created a toast like above and want to change the TextColor property.

using C# +XAML + Win8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change foreground color in manifest file.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible because the Toast Notification is a system internal function and the color is given by the user setting background color.